# Average of selected rows in csv file

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

In a csv file, how can i calculate the average of selected rows in a column:
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMbTL.jpg)

I did this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Read the csv file:
df = pd.read_csv("D:\\xxxxx\\mmmmm.csv")

#Separate the columns and get the average:
#       Skid:
S = df['Skid Number after milling'].mean()
```

But this just gave me the average for the entire column

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't believe the rows you have selected in excel are stored in the csv file

Comment: I didnt select any rows, i want to select just rows for all positions 1 and get the average of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting rows in a pandas dataframe or series you can use the `.iloc` attribute.

For example `df['A'].iloc[3:5]` selects the fourth and fifth row in column "A" of a DataFrame. Indexing starts at 0 and the number behind the colon is not included. This returns a pandas series.

You can do the same using numpy: `df["A"].values[3:5]`
This already returns a numpy array.

Possibilities to calculate the mean are therefore.

`df['A'].iloc[3:5].mean()`
or 
`df["A"].values[3:5].mean()`

Also see [the documentation about indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) in pandas.

Comment: If this answers your question, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. If it doesn't, feel free to narrow down your question. If, in addition, this or other answers you find are useful consider upvoting them.